How can I further clean fix geometries if the tool doesn't fix them all?
I'm trying to clean up a spatial file (a constituency map of France) to then use in Tableau. I used the "fix geometries" tool to fix most of the issue, but there are still several constituencies that are invalid after using the tool.
How can I go through and fix these in the most efficient way possible? Do I have any other options other than going through each section individually and manually fixing whatever is wrong?

How do you know they are invalid; is there an error message or are you running the Check Validity tool or Topology Checker geometry rule on the result as a check and it finds some?  The Check Validity tool has a few options including the method and whether you want to ignore self-intersections or not.   I'd also look at running the GRASS v.clean tool with a suitable threshold using the break, snap and bpol tools and then fix geometries again.

I usually try:

Fix geometries

If that is not enough any or all of:

If you have a polygon layer Buffer with 0 or a very small distance
Snap points to grid
Simplify with a very small tolerance

But sometimes this does not fix all errors. If you have access to ArcGIS it can do a better job.
